# Progress of a process in a website with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a website with c# and I have a process that lasts between 1 and 4 seconds (uploading data from database).
I want that I show a bar or image_process for waiting(from when I click on the button that import data from the database until displaying that data on my Gridview)

I found this code but this code contains another button..I don't need another button..I want that my previous one import data and display the waiting image.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
            OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
     </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
   <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" 
   AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ProgressTemplate><img src="animatedprogress.jpg"/></ProgressTemplate>   
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Comment: Please don't post code in comments since it is totally unreadable there. Use `edit` link below your question and post code in question with appropriate formatting.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want here.  If you don't want an extra button, remove it.  What are you having problems with?

Comment: how to display the progress image with my previous button..my previous button executes a method named "test_data"

Comment: has anyone here an idea?